# M1 Mac: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820)

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, cucumber, apple-m1, cucumber-java

I am trying to run an automation test by launching the Chrome browser using the chrome driver.

Setup:

```
Chip: Apple M1 Pro
OS: macOS Monterey
JDK: jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk
Maven: Apache Maven 3.8.5
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Community Edition)Build #IC-221.5591.52
```

When I run my code, I get the following errors:
Could you please suggest a solution? No idea something wrong with the setup, version, Pom or chromedriver path:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820) at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:574) at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:530) at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.(LocalizedXStreams.java:50) at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37) at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29) at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37) at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300) at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44) at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39) at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44) at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165) at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122) at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36) at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18) at ?.Given I launch a browser(/Users/ravithapa/IdeaProjects/letstry/src/test/resources/Features/Homepagelogo_Login.feature:5) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @179d3b25 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174) at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:39) at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.(TreeMapConverter.java:50) at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820) at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:574) at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:530) at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.(LocalizedXStreams.java:50) at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37) at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29) at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37) at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300) at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44) at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39) at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44) at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165) at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122) at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36) at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)

Pom file:
4.0.0

```html
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>letstry</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.19</version>
      <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>execution</id>
          <phase>test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <projectName>e2e</projectName>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
            <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
  <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit  -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
  </dependency>
  <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java  -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java  -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit  -->


  <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer  -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin  -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.28</version>
  </dependency>
  <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver  -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.48.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>


<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

code:

```
public WebDriver driver;

    @Given("^I launch a browser$")
    public void i_launch_a_browser() throws Throwable {
```

```html
public class Homepagelogo_Login {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @Given("^I launch a browser$")
    public void i_launch_a_browser() throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/me/Desktop/test/webdriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

    }
```

Comment: That code is ancient and your JVM can't run it. Start over with https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Add following to the VM options in the Run configuration of your IDE:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Reference from here: https://github.com/Riduidel/aadarchi/issues/90#issuecomment-1291640544

The above link also has sample code to use in pom.xml if you are running a `mvn test` instead.